# How to Add CNAM to Twillio

Tags: twilio

We want Caller ID to display our company name on outbound calls. 
According to Twilio, numbers purchased from them cannot have Caller ID/CNAM added.
If we transfer numbers from another service that can add the numbers, will the CallerID/CNAM be maintained.
Should we Port the Number or have Twilio host the number? What is the difference?

Tried to purchase numbers on Twilio and have CNAM added.
Have purchased numbers from another vendor and they were able to add CallerID

Comment: I think contacting Twilio might be your best bet here to get the official word from them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience recently migrating several numbers to Twilio:

1. If we transfer numbers from another service that can add the numbers, will the CallerID/CNAM be maintained?

   - Supposedly yes, mine did not. I had three Spectrum landlines, with working outbound caller ID. At some point after porting them to Twilio, the caller ID disappeared. What's worse is that some cellphones will try and "guess," and show random people's names instead of my business name (or at least, nothing).
2. What is the difference between porting and hosted numbers?

   > Hosted SMS provides a method for customers to use Twilio’s Programmable Messaging, Functions and Studio products to send and receive messages on voice-enabled numbers they already own as part of an established voice application.
   >   (from https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/hosted-numbers)

   So porting is moving the number entirely to Twilio as the carrier for the number - voice, SMS, possibly fax (although Twilio's fax support is minimal). A hosted number would just enable SMS through Twilio for a non-Twilio landline number.

I have been looking for a way to get my numbers listed back in the CNAM database(s), today I tried a company called TrueCNAM (https://www.truecnam.com/) who will let you list up to five numbers for free. I went ahead and listed mine, I'll update my answer if I verify that it's working. Currently the CNAM lookup for my numbers is blank, so we'll see what happens.

Edit: I also tried verifying my number at https://listyourself.net, but I'm still not seeing the number in a couple searches I've done on it. It looks like the changes may take a while to propagate to the downstream third-party CNAM databases, based on this: https://www.dslreports.com/forum/r26461709-

Comment: Not yet - but the only test I've been using is the one at https://apeiron.io/cnam, and it seems like all of these services have access to varying different databases, which eventually may (or may not) propagate to the other ones. 

I would be happy to try another (free) CNAM lookup tool if you can suggest one.